# Removing Duplicates From a list while keeping the most recent C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, rfid

So I have several lists of type Tag.  Tag has several properties: .Epc , .AntennaPortNumber, and .LastTimeSeen.  I want to take all of the Tags from the main list, and sort them into 5 smaller lists, but only keep one copy of each .Epc and it must be the most recent .LastTimeSeen.  I am not really sure where to even begin.  I was thinking I must need to do something with .GroupBy nested a couple times?  right now the code is split into two main parts: where I add new tags to the lists they belong in, and where I remove a tag that has not been seen for 500ms.  I attempted to prevent duplicate tags from being added to the 5 sublists with .Contains, but because they have different LastTimeSeen properties this is not having the desired effect.

Thanks for any guidance anyone might be able to provide!

```
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> listMed1 = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> listMed2 = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> listMed3 = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> listMed4 = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> listMed5 = new List<Tag>();
    void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
    {
        // This event handler is called asynchronously 
        // when tag reports are available.
        // Loop through each tag in the report 
        // and print the data.



        //List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (Tag tag in report)
        {

            ushort AntennaNum = tag.AntennaPortNumber;


            Impinj.OctaneSdk.TagData first = tag.Epc;

            string epcCheck = first.ToString().ToUpper();
            Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp tim = tag.LastSeenTime;

            if (epcCheck.IndexOf("A") != -1)
            {

                if (listMed1.Contains(tag) == false)
                {
                    listMed1.Add(tag);
                    System. Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(epcCheck);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tim);
                }
            }

            else if (epcCheck.IndexOf("B") != -1)
            {
                if (listMed2.Contains(tag) == false)
                {
                    listMed2.Add(tag);
                }
            }
            else if (epcCheck.IndexOf("C") != -1)
            {
                if (listMed3.Contains(tag) == false)
                {
                    listMed3.Add(tag);
                }
            }
            else if (epcCheck.IndexOf("D") != -1)
            {
                if (listMed1.Contains(tag) == false)
                {
                    listMed4.Add(tag);
                }
            }
            else if (epcCheck.IndexOf("E") != -1)
            {
                if (listMed5.Contains(tag) == false)
                {
                    listMed5.Add(tag);
                }
            }



            int Med1num = listMed1.Count();
            int Med2num = listMed2.Count();
            int Med3num = listMed3.Count();
            int Med4num = listMed4.Count();
            int Med5num = listMed5.Count();

            for (int loopr = 0; loopr < Med1num; loopr++)
            {
                Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = listMed1[loopr].LastSeenTime;
                string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
                long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
                TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 500 )
                {
                    listMed1.RemoveAt(loopr);
                    loopr = -1;
                }

            }
            for (int loopr = 0; loopr < Med2num; loopr++)
            {
                Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = listMed2[loopr].LastSeenTime;
                string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
                long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
                TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 500)
                {
                    listMed2.RemoveAt(loopr);
                    loopr = -1;
                }

            }
            for (int loopr = 0; loopr < Med3num; loopr++)
            {
                Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = listMed3[loopr].LastSeenTime;
                string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
                long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
                TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 500)
                {
                    listMed3.RemoveAt(loopr);
                    loopr = -1;
                }

            }
            for (int loopr = 0; loopr < Med4num; loopr++)
            {
                Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = listMed4[loopr].LastSeenTime;
                string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
                long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
                TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 500)
                {
                    listMed4.RemoveAt(loopr);
                    loopr = -1;
                }

            }
            for (int loopr = 0; loopr < Med5num; loopr++)
            {
                Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = listMed5[loopr].LastSeenTime;
                string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
                long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
                TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 500)
                {
                    listMed5.RemoveAt(loopr);
                    loopr = -1;
                }

            }

             Med1num = listMed1.Count();
             Med2num = listMed2.Count();
             Med3num = listMed3.Count();
             Med4num = listMed4.Count();
             Med5num = listMed5.Count();

            SetText(Med1num, Med2num, Med3num, Med4num, Med5num);

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that the `TagReport` parameter is a list of updated tags? It isn't the entire list, but over time, more `TagsReported` events fire, that you're building up for `listMed{X}` lists from the tags in `TagReport`.

Comment: Am I correct in saying the following. You add ALL tags to you list named tag. Then from this list you move the tag into listMed1, listMed2 etc depending where they belong. If a tag has not been seen in < 500 ms it is removed from tag or listMed1, listMed2...?

Comment: both of your questions are answered with: yes.

Comment: Will tags always only be in one of the lists? They don't change lists?

Comment: Yes, they will always only be in one of the listMed1-5.

Comment: When you say you prevent duplicates from being added do you mean the following: You added a tag to listMed1 at say 13h45. Now a similar tag is being added at 14h30. Would you have to remove the first or second one from listMed1?

Comment: Could the second of two calls to the `OnTagsReported` handler have the same tag with an earlier `.LastTimeSeen` than the first call?

Comment: I would like to remove all previous occurances of any tag, only keeping the instance of each tag with the most recent time being seen. So the first one  would be removed.  This way I can check against the time stamp to see if it has been seen in the last 500ms, and remove it from the list if it has not.

Comment: no, the .LastTimeSeen will always be later in the second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
/// <summary>The group</summary>
enum eGroup : byte
{
    A, B, C, D, E
};
static IEnumerable<eGroup> allGroups()
{
    return Enum.GetValues( typeof( eGroup ) ).Cast<eGroup>();
}
/// <summary>Classify tag to the group, returns null if failed.</summary>
static eGroup? classify( Tag tag )
{
    string str = tag.Epc.ToString().ToUpper();
    foreach( eGroup e in allGroups() )
        if( str.Contains( e.ToString ) )
            return e;
    return null;
}

/// <summary>Add tag to list unless it's already there.</summary>
static void addToList( List<Tag> list, Tag t )
{
    int ind = list.IndexOf( t );
    if( ind < 0 )
        list.Add( t );  // Not on the list
    else if( list[ ind ].LastSeenTime.Utc < t.LastSeenTime.Utc )
        list[ ind ] = t; // Only replace if newer then the existing one
}

/// <summary>The collection to hold all that groups.</summary>
readonly Dictionary<eGroup, List<Tag>> med = allGroups().ToDictionary( e => e, e => new List<Tag>() );

/// <summary>True if that tag is too old.</summary>
static bool isTooOld( Tag t )
{
    ImpinjTimestamp ts = t.LastSeenTime;
    DateTime utc = new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc ).AddTicks( (long)ts.Utc * 10L );
    return ( DateTime.UtcNow - utc ).TotalMilliseconds > 500;
}

void OnTagsReported( ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report )
{
    // Classify and add to the correct group
    foreach( Tag tag in report )
    {
        eGroup? group = classify( tag );
        if( !group.HasValue ) continue;
        addToList( med[ group.Value ], tag );
    }
    // Remove too old tags
    foreach( var list in med.Values )
        list.RemoveAll( isTooOld );

    // Show counts
    int[] c = allGroups().Select( e => med[ e ].Count ).ToArray();
    SetText( c[ 0 ], c[ 1 ], c[ 2 ], c[ 3 ], c[ 4 ] );
}
```

Comment: there is some sort of problem with passing the groups into SetText though.  I tried private void SetText(List<Tag> med[eGroup.A] , List<Tag> med[eGroup.B], List<Tag> med[eGroup.C], List<Tag> med[eGroup.D], List<Tag> med[eGroup.E])

Comment: duplicate parameter, and A, B, C, D, E does not exist in Form1.eGroup

Comment: 1 - see the update 2 - you probably failed to copy-paste correctly

Comment: sorry, missed the edit.  Now no tags are added to the lists however

Comment: You’ll have to debug yourself.

Comment: Two likely reasons - either classify() returns null, or isTooOld() returns true. BTW if you're running that in debugger and using breakpoints/step over, the lists may stay empty forever because 500ms is too fast.

Comment: yeah, I tried a few longer times so I guess it must be returning null on all the tags

Comment: just checked though, not returning null.  it is returning the letter it should be for each one

Comment: Then probably the time is wrong, so they're added then removed 'coz older then 500ms

Comment: It’s very hard to implement DateTime correctly. Authors of that library failed to use MS-provided System.DateTime, they instead use their own ImpinjTimestamp…

Comment: changing the threshold of the time, even to something as high as 100000, doesn't yield any tags being added though.

Comment: OH you know what. it shouldnt be being romoved if its too old. it should be being removed if it isnt seen again within 500ms.

Comment: though this might not be an important distinction

Comment: Just comment two lines after // Remove too old tags and verify it works.

Comment: the ImpinjTimestamp is just milliseconds since the Unix Epoch

Comment: after commenting: it does add tags, so it must be the removal of tags that is the issue.  Also, it only updates the text of the first text box until I stop the reads. (it doesnt do this when the lines are not commented, so its probably not a concern)

Comment: If you sure about milliseconds, replace AddTicks( (long)ts.Utc * 10L ); with AddTicks( (long)ts.Utc * 10000L );

Comment: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

Comment: I changed the tooOld calculate the time difference the way I had been previously and it grew uncontrollably as if the lists were not having old values replaced by new ones. SO I changed it back to the way you had done it originally

Comment: This means they aren't "just milliseconds since the Unix Epoch". Research how exactly does that crappy third-party library represents time, and how to convert to UTC System.DateTime

Comment: my bad, microseconds

Comment: In this case my original code is OK. Then your symptoms could mean there’s a bug in that library, and value returned by LastSeenTime is incorrect (could be e.g. in some other time zone, not UTC). Use debugger to watch the value of "utc" local variable to confirm.

Comment: hadnt considered it might be in another timezone. Upon checking they are indeed in different timezones and the reader believes it to be 2001:
3/23/2016 8:38:43 AM
6/11/2001 6:36:16 AM

Comment: Fix your reader then, research why it's returning invalid dates.

Comment: OK, SO I have come up with a way to remove time from the equation entirely, but I need a quick bit of help to make it work.  How can I make sure all of the lists are empty at the beginning of every OnTagsReported?  I found a reader mode in the docs that reads each tag only once, so I'm just going to do that every time the door to my cabinet is closed, and then everything will be okay.

Comment: nevermind, figured it out!  Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is all you might need:

```
void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
{
    tags.RemoveAll(tag => report.Select(r => r.Epc).Contains(tag.Epc));

    tags.AddRange(report);

    tags.RemoveAll(tag =>
    {
        Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp second = tag.LastSeenTime;
        string milisecondsUTC = second.ToString();
        long lastseen = Convert.ToInt64(milisecondsUTC);
        TimeSpan t = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        long secondsSinceEpoch = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;
        return secondsSinceEpoch - lastseen > 5000;
    });

    var counts =
            new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", }
                .Select(c =>
                    tags
                        .Where(tag => tag.Epc.ToString().IndexOf(c) != -1)
                        .Count())
                .ToArray();

    SetText(counts[0], counts[1], counts[2], counts[3], counts[4]);
}
```

The `counts` definition might be the only thing to cause grief, but I can make it work if this basic way of doing it doesn't give you the results you need.

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.

---

Here's the object models I created for testing purposes. It allow the OP's code and my code to compile.

```
public void SetText(params int[] xs) { }

public class Impinj
{
    public class OctaneSdk
    {
        public class TagData { }
        public class ImpinjTimestamp { }
    }
}

public class ImpinjReader { }

public class TagReport : List<Tag> { }

public class Tag
{
    public ushort AntennaPortNumber;
    public Impinj.OctaneSdk.TagData Epc;
    public Impinj.OctaneSdk.ImpinjTimestamp LastSeenTime;
}
```

Comment: report is a TagReport not a Tag, so it doesnt have .select and cannot be added to a List<tag> like "tags"

Comment: So I tried creating another list of all the tags in report, and then replacing report with the name of that list in your code, and it adds a lot of duplicates

Comment: @Lodestone6 - `TagReport` is used in the `foreach` loop so it must at least be `IEnumerable<Tag>` which means you can use a `.Select` against it.

Comment: @Lodestone6 - I'll add the object model that I created to make your code compile and which I could test against. Can you tell me if it looks OK?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Sets if you want to prevent duplicates. Depending on your needs a TreeSet could be used for sorted data, in which case you must make sure Tag implements IComparable. Otherwise a HashSet should fit nicely.
In case you want to continue using Lists you **must** override the Equals method on Tag. Given your code we cant see the structure of Tag, but you use the List.Contains method. You should implement Equals with disregard to LastTimeSeen.
You also shouldnt use IndexOf in that way as it kind of obscures the code, you should be able to replace it with String.Contains. Using Linq as Enigmativity suggested could also greatly clean up your code.

If you do not have access to the source code of that library you should make a helper method or extension method on the collection of choice in which you check for equality.